# Empty first tab lost when using sessions

Tags: tabbed-user-interface, sessions

I'm creating a session with `mksession`, and when I restore the session, if the first tab was empty (`[No Name]`), it's gone in the restored session. Other empty tabs are restored fine; it seems to only be the first tab that's lost. If there are multiple "leading" empty tabs, it's still only the first one that disappears.

I'm using this with `vim -u NONE` so there is zero config and no plugins, but I get the same behavior with my normal config. Affects versions 7.3 and 8.0.52.

I'm using the default `sessionoptions` in all cases: `blank,buffers,curdir,folds,options,tabpages,winsize`.

Steps to reproduce:

- `$ vim -u NONE`
- `:tabnew`
- `:e foo.txt`
- `:w`
- `:tabnew`
- `:mksession`
- `:qa`
- `$ vim -u NONE -S Session.vim`

The tabline now shows `foo.txt | [No Name]`. Expected `[No Name] | foo.txt | [No Name]`.

Is this a known issue? Is there a workaround?

Comment: I can confirm it behaves like this. Sounds like a bug? This is probably best reported to the vim_dev list or the GitHub issue tracker.

Comment: I'll report it on both and look into a fix. I use a [plugin I wrote](https://github.com/fweep/vim-tabber) which uses fixed, labeled tabs so this messes with my workflow a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed a bug in Vim. I filed a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1282), and someone on the vim-dev mailing list addressed it.

Here's a patch that fixes it in Vim 8.0.52:

```
diff --git a/src/ex_docmd.c b/src/ex_docmd.c
index 439467c..ca4133a 100644
--- a/src/ex_docmd.c
+++ b/src/ex_docmd.c
@@ -11091,6 +11091,8 @@ makeopens(
        }
        if (tabnr > 1)
        need_tabnew = TRUE;
+       else if (put_line(fd, "new") == FAIL)
+       return FAIL;
    }

    /*
```

Patch courtesy Hirohito Higashi on the vim-dev mailing list. I imagine it will make its way into the official distribution.

**Update:**

This was fixed in Vim 8.1.0149 (see [GitHub PR](https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/3152)).